# Android application install failed

Tags: android, installation, apk

This might perhaps seem like a bit of a simple question but I'm stuck none the less.

Im trying to install an application on my phone, just to test it out.
However when trying to install it just gives me the error message "Application not installed"

Can't for the life of me see what's wrong, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I believe you either have an earlier version of the app already on the device or you haven't enabled 'Download from unknown sources' in your device settings.

Comment: In most cases it happens if you duplicate your old project and rename new created project name. But package name of your main activity stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem might happen from followed reasons:

- Before installation you had other application with the same process name
- Its really installed but `adb` tells you "Application not installed"

Restart `adb`.
Uninstall any application with the same name or process by using `adb uninstal yourapplicationname`

Comment: Thanks a million! Was a previous installation messing it up!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error `"Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UNKNOWN_SOURCES]"`, as it said it is caused by an UNKOWN_SOURCES, which is, in this case adb.

I solve this problem by just change some security setting. You can find it on your device.